# iPhone 12 Pro, 13 Pro Max take super-bright (maybe overexposed) photos with flash

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift5, bug-reporting, avcapturephotooutput

On the current project once again I use the camera.
I use two streams of video and photo Video to detect rectangle and photo to capture a photo with the flash. After several checks I found the bug. On 12 Pro & 13 Pro Max in a bright room I obtain overexposed photos, if I do the same in a dark room, there are no overexposed photos. This behavior is not available on older iPhones.

[image]

I look forward to all your suggestions and comments.

Environment: iOS 15.4.1, iPhone 12, 12 Pro, 12 Pro Max, 13, 13 Pro, 13Pro Max

Additional info: I capture photo in -

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {...}
```

Comment: Any luck solving this? Does it also happen when the flash doesn't fire?

Answer (score 0):

So what I've discovered to help is `AVCapturePhotoSettings`'s `isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled`, which is deprecated since iOS 13, with a reference to `photoQualityPrioritization`.
Using `.balance` or `.quality` (and setting the same on `AVCapturePhotoOutput`) didn't help, but `.speed` did.

Comment: Thanks @Zoltán, I'll try soon and come back with an answer...